# Embedding Highcharts-Editor within ReactJS web app and pulling data from DB

Tags: reactjs, asp.net-web-api, highcharts, highcharts-editor

I am currently working on a college final year project and I am trying to embed a Simple Modal Editor version of highcharts-editor within my ReactJS application. ( see here http://editor.highcharts.com/simplemodal.html )

I would like to open the modal editor and rather than import data from uploads, pull data from the database using my .Net Core 2.0 Web API and customize and generate my chart from there. However, I am unsure on how I would complete this

I am having difficulty finding any documentation on how I should import this plugin into my React application and also how I could modify the modal to pull in my data rather than from file uploads. I am also fairly inexperienced in React (learning the language as I study).

Any help or pointers would be greatly, greatly appreciated.

Comment: Have you seen this documentation?: https://github.com/highcharts/highcharts-editor There're some integration examples that might be very helpful.

Comment: Hi Kamil, thanks for your reply. I have seen this documentation, however it doesnt really help regarding embedding the editor within a reactJS app. I also couldnt find anything useful on how to pull in your own data rather than just populating data within the modal

Comment: I'd advise you to set up the editor in pure JS and then try to move it to React.  It seems that uploading the data is handled in this file: https://github.com/highcharts/highcharts-editor/blob/master/src/core/highed.fileupload.js You may want to analyze it and implement your own logic. If you have a specific problem please share your code and describe it with details.

Comment: Thank you for your help Kamil! I am just starting to implement it now, but I was unsure as to how to embed it into a React app, if I encounter any more difficulty I update my original post. Thanks